# Symfony 2 how to set up fallback

Tags: symfony

I am trying to do translation of my project.

I have created translation files in src/AppBundle/Translations/

en_EN.yml

```
title : Welcome to my Blog!
welcome.text : Hello! It's my personal blog.
welcome.text.description : I'm gonna use this for showing what i can :)

menu.main : Main

sidebar.account.anonymous : Log in
sidebar.account.logged : Account
sidebar.about.title : About me
sidebar.about.text : My name is Tigran Muradyan. Besides programming, I have lots of hobbies. One of them - playing on piano :)
sidebar.contact.title : Contact me

user.login : Login
user.password : Password
user.remember : Remember me
user.gender : Gender
user.phone : Phone
user.email : Email
user.about : About me
user.account.information : Account information
user.logout : Log out


article.creation.date : Creation date
article.author : Author
article.read.more : Read more

comments : Comments
comments.anonymous : Please log in to leave a comment.
comments.logged : Leave a comment
```

ru_RU.yml

```
title : Добро пожаловать на мой блог!
welcome.text : Привет! Это мой личный блог.
welcome.text.description : Я использую его, чтобы показать, что я умею :)

menu.main : Главная

sidebar.account.anonymous : Зайдите на сайт
sidebar.account.logged : Профиль
sidebar.about.title : Обо мне
sidebar.about.text : Меня зовут Тигран Мурадян. Помимо программирования, у меня есть много хобби. Одно из них - фортепиано :)
sidebar.contact.title : Свяжитесь со мной

user.login : Логин
user.password : Пароль
user.remember : Запомнить
user.gender : Пол
user.phone : Телефон
user.email : Электронная почта
user.about : Обо мне
user.account.information : Информация о аккаунте
user.logout : Выйти


article.creation.date : Дата публикации
article.author : Автор
article.read.more : Читать подбробнее

comments : Комментарии
comments.anonymous : Пожалуйста, зайдите под своим аккаунтом. чтобы оставить комментарий.
comments.logged : Оставить комментарий
```

But when i put in template {{welcome.text|trans}}, it says no variable found.

I think the problem is in my translation settings. Here they are

```
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true
```

How should i set up translations and how they should be loaded?

Thank you

Edit:

paramaters.yml

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_host: localhost
    database_port: null
    database_name: blog
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: a2cb7f1e0ff91931e4c325b072ba3b6e34af4aa6
```

Comment: What's the value of your `%locale%` parameter? The configuration seems okay, but maybe that parameter isn't set. Try to change it to a fixed setting for testing purposes.

Comment: Not sure where it should be set. I do not fully understand documentation

Comment: try to move your transation files in the resources folder as `src/AppBundle/Resources/Translations/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have no variable `welcome.text` have you? If you use text without apostrophes Twig expect variables instead of text. Proper way is:

```
{{ 'welcome.text' | trans }}
```

Comment: it is displaying welcome.text. How should i load those files/

Comment: Move files to proper place as @Matteo suggested http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#book-translation-resource-locations

Comment: Moved. And defined locale: en_EN in parameters.yml, still no effect. How should i define locale?

Comment: Still nothin, malcolm, can we please move to chat?

Comment: We can, but just try one more time: set locale to `en`, move and rename files to `Resources/translations/messages.en.yml` and clear cache after that.

Comment: yes it worked, but still got few questions, it will be to long here, can u please start a chat?

Comment: Just read documentation, or make another question, have no time now sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89720/discussion-between-malcolm-and-tigran-muradyan).

Answer (score 0):

Full framework documentation can found on: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#translator

It seems your `%locale%` parameter is missing, which should be defined in `parameters.yml.dist`.

After `composer install` that parameters file is parsed into `parameters.yml`.

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html

Comment: Just did composer update. I have parameters.yml, but no locale parameter. It is not in parameters.yml.dist either. Should i add %locale% by my own? and how it should look like?